# jQuery - Identify and mark link in textarea

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, textarea, href

I have a textarea

```
<textarea id="postContent" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Tell us about it!" rows="4"></textarea>
```

and I need a script that highlights the links written inside the textarea, stores them in a variable (array) for later processing and removes all html-tags. The behavior is well-know from the tweet-box on twitter.

So the content could be

> Look what I have found today on www.stackoverflow.com!

and in that case, www.stackoverflow.com should be highlighted (wrapped in a `<p>` f.e.) without the "!".

How would you do that with jQuery?

Comment: I guess an event listener on keyup and regexp matcher?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Also, google Regular Expressions.

Comment: this could prove way trickier than you probably think - just read up on [CodeMirror creator's story](http://codemirror.net/1/story.html)

Comment: I didn't even know where to start and wanted to ask here if you know a library or even a jQuery-plugin that does the job. Thanks for the answers so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to highlight link then you have to work with innerHTML of textarea....(I would not suggest that) your regex goes here = var regEx = /((ht|f)tps?://\S*)/g;

Secondly, you can identify links using click event inside textarea...click handler should look whether it is a url or plain text..if a link open new window..else return false....